# DataProvider sequence in TestNG

Tags: selenium, automation, testng

Do we need to follow the same sequence in array object while using the dataObject

Eg: Code

```
 @DataProvider(name = "test1")
     public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {
            return new Object[][] {{2, true}, {6, false}, {19, true}, {22, false}, {23, true}};
     }

     // This test will run 4 times since we have 5 parameters defined
     @Test(dataProvider = "test1")
     public void testPrimeNumberChecker(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) {
            System.out.println(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult,
            primeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
     }
```

In `DataProvider` `Integer` and `Boolean` are used and same sequence is used in `testPrimeNumberChecker`. Can I use only `Boolean` record in any of the function if I need.

Answer (score 1):

**Type, number** and **order/sequence** of input parameters of `@Test` method must be same as passed by `@DataProvider` method.

> Do we need to follow the same sequence in array object while **using** the `dataObject`

Here I assume by **using** you mean to passing the arguments in the `@Test` method. **Answer** of this is - **Yes** we need to follow the same sequence in array object while using the `dataObject`.

**Example**:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
     public void testPrimeNumberChecker(Boolean expectedResult, Integer inputNumber) {
// your test method stuff
}
```

If you do not follow this you will get below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

> Can I use only Boolean record in any of the function if I need.

Here also I am assuming by **use** you mean to passing the arguments in the `@Test` method. Answer is - **No**, number of arguments matters.

**Example**:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
     public void testPrimeNumberChecker(Boolean expectedResult) {
// your test method stuff
}
```

So if your `@Test` method has less or more number of input parameter(s) what your `@DataProvider` method passes, you will get below exception:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The data provider is trying to pass 2 parameters but the method yourpackage.YourTestClass#testPrimeNumberChecker takes 1
```